# I am trying to install vdebug on vim, having trouble with ./vim

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I am on an amazon ec2 server, in the home folder. I created the ./vim folder. I can not get the plugin to work. Maybe it is a permissions error? Permissions are currently se to drwxrwxr-x

https://howchoo.com/g/ztmyntqzntm/how-to-install-vim-plugins-without-a-plugin-manager

https://github.com/vim-vdebug/vdebug

$pwd
/home/user/.vim/bundle

git clone https://github.com/vim-vdebug/vdebug.git

$ls
vdebug

:set runtimepath^=~/.vim/bundle/ctrlp.vim
:help Vdebug

E149: Sorry, no help for Vdebug

Comment: 1) You installed `~/.vim/bundle/vdebug` but you are telling Vim there's code for it in `~/.vim/bundle/ctrlp.vim`; 2) You did not use `:helptags` to make sure the plugin's help is indexed; 3) Plugin managers exist for a reason.

Comment: I tried following instructions here to get VIM-plug working, honestly I can't tell if it is working or not https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/388/what-is-the-difference-between-the-vim-plugin-managers. I moved it to `~/.vim/bundle/ctrlp.vim` `$ls
bootstrap.sh  features  python3    spec    Vagrantfile
build.sh      Gemfile   Rakefile   syntax  vdebug-2.0.0.tar.gz
CHANGELOG     LICENCE   README.md  tags    VERSION
doc           plugin    rubylib    tests`, ran `$source build.sh `. I am not sure what I am doing wrong, or how to use the plugin manager. Helptags got me no results.

Comment: ...why would you move Vdebug plugin to `~/.vim/bundle/ctrlp.vim`? It's like putting dogfood in jar labeled "Cookies"...? If I were you, I would delete everything in `.vim` and start over. Vdebug page has install instructions. If you're doing manual installation, don't use `bundle` directory, do exactly what `Vdebug` manual installation says:"Clone or download a tarball of the plugin and move its content in your `~/.vim/` directory. You should call `:helptags ~/.vim/doc` to generate the necessary help tags afterwards." If you do use VimPlug, again, follow the instructions by VimPlug and Vdebug.

Comment: Thank you Amadan, that worked